# How to make Custom login registration and logout with auth laravel?

Tags: laravel

> **I'm trying to make the first project with laravel but it .. please help**

Comment: how do you want to custom it? you can just copy the default one and modify it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. You must add the user model to the models folder, and the user table to your database.
Next, you need to arrange a controller in which you will receive a request from web routes.

In the controller, you take the parameters of the request. In case of registration, write the data to the users table.

In case of login. Checking the password.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

public static function checkAttempt($credentials):bool
{
    $user = User:: where('login',  'like', $credentials['login'])->firstorFail();
    $validPassword = Hash::check($credentials['password'], $user['password']);
    return $user && $validPassword && $user['user_active'];
}
```

This is the password verification function.

This documentation can also help you.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#included-authenticating